# Date condition (visits)

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to make a condition where if the registry has the same the same image as the same date cannot be saved

```
public function validateVisit()
{   
    if (Visit::find()->where(['date_visit'=>$this->date_visit])->all()) {
       if (Visit::find()->where(['imagen_id'=>$this->imagen_id])->all()) {
          $this->addError('imagen_id', 'Already exists this visit within the range.');
        } 
    } 
}
```

In my code it does not save when the image that is entered already exists in the database, in my case, I require that you do not save when the same date that is entered with the same image already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unique` validator for this.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['imagen_id'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['imagen_id', 'date_visit']],
        // ... other validations ...
    ];
}
```

The first item in rule definition `['date_visit']` says to what attribute the error will be set. The `targetAttribute` define combination of attributes that must be unique. In this case the validation will only pass when the combination of `imagen_id` and `date_visit` attributes doesn't exist.

See more about [unique validator](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator).

Comment: Well. Thank you!